# Changes not reflecting to extended site

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, custom-masterpage, extended

We have extended web application for FBA users.

I did changes to master pages of main site, still the changes are not reflecting in extended site.

What could be the reason? How can I make the changes available in extended site too?

I am aware that there is some job which runs and replicates the changes to extended site as well. But not sure about the job name or its schedule/ frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did silly mistake. Master page was just checked in.

Master page needs Approval to reflect changes in extended site too. Make sure you do approval of master page after any changes.